# gnupg: display digest of key

Tags: pgp

How can I display what digest algorithm has a key? If I import a public key which has MD5 as digest, I get a warning about this weak algorith. But how can I check, what digest algorithms all my keys use in my keyring?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about _using_ a cryptographic program

Comment: To clarify, this website is about the science of cryptography, and how one develops/applies cryptographic designs. Your question is about how to use a product already developed, rather like asking 'Where is the ignition in a Ford Focus?' on a 'Mechanical engineering' site.  Hope that made sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gpg --list-packets [keyfile]` to see a list of all packets and their contents. All hash algorithms have numbers which you can look up in [section 9.4 of RFC 4880, "Hash Algorithms"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-9.4).

Alternatively, use `pgpdump [keyfile]` to create a similar output, but already containing the algorithm names instead of their numeric identifiers.

Comment: `gpg --list-packets [keyfile] --verbose` tells me that there is 3069 bits raw data. What else is there? Are these really all packets and their contents?

Comment: `gpg --list-packets` is already dumping all details on what's included -- you might have to read RFC 4880 (OpenPGP) to understand the details, though.